# After passing a checkride, can I get the plastic certificate card by visiting the nearest FSDO?

Tags: faa, pilot-certification, fsdo

As you know, it takes more than 30 days for the plastic certificate card to be delivered. I know that right after passing check-ride, the temporary certificate is given but I need a plastic card to convert US pilot license to my country license. My government does not accept the temporary paper certificate. Is there any way to get a plastic certificate card from the nearest FSDO as fast as possible?

Answer (score 2):

No, sorry. They don’t have the device at the FSDO that would produce a plastic card.

If you want to see the page that shows what date they are currently processing for, [click here.](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/airmen_certification/)

Unfortunately it’s typically around 6-8 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

No, FSDO's do not issue the plastic cards. Your only option is to wait.

Processing time takes quite a while. For example, it is November 13 and the FAA is currently processing applications that were submitted on October 3. The process to actually receive your plastic license can take from 30 days (unlikely) to over 3 months. I think on average the time from application to license in your hand is about 60 days.

Comment: Hmm.. I’d better check in with them. I got my UAS certificate more than 90 days ago and still haven’t got my plastic card.

Comment: @Canuk Look up your info on the airman registry. If your information is there, the application has probably been processed and you should have received the card (within a couple weeks of that status updating). If you haven't, I'd apply for a replacement.

Comment: Found out there was another reason.  Just takes a long time to transit information between Oklahoma City and my local FSDO, apparently.